# How to find if solr index is corrupted

Tags: indexing, solr

Is there any api in Solr that will check if index is corrupted or not? In my project I am writing a diagnostic tool to check the index health of the solr and wondering if there is any api for that.

Answer (score 0):

there is a Lucene tool, called CheckIndex, as Solr indexes are just lucene indexes under the hood, you can use it to verify their integrity.

[Here is a recent post](https://support.lucidworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/202091128-How-to-deal-with-Index-Corruption) about how to use it. And you can always check the javadocs for CheckIndex in your current Lucene version you are using in Solr.

Comment: Thanks for reply... but I know this tool, what I want is if there is any api build in in solr or lucene to check the solr corruption at run time.